# TFS 2010 Team Project Portal Setting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-templates

I am not seeing the out of the box workbooks that come with MSF for Agile Software Development v5.0 in my Team Project. Turns out, TFS stores the Excel files for the template in the SharePoint portal that needs to be specified in the project settings.

From the Project Settings, There seems to be two different ways in which you can specify the Porject Portal location:

[image]

**My Question:**

1. I am not sure why "Use this SharePoint Site" is listed as (Not configured)? Does the Team Foundation Server needs to have a local SharePoint instal for this option to be enabled? Or is it some kind of permission issue?
2. Also, when I enter the SharePoint site collection root URL in the "Use a Web site" textbox, there is not much change in the situation. How is one supposed to use this option?
3. Does this mean that in order to use the workbook one needs to install SharePoint in TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the workbook you do not need sharepoint. What you need to do is go to the Team Project Collection Node and right click and choose Process Template Manager, Download the process template on to your local computer. Go to the folder and you will see the excel workbook, you will be able to use the workbook.

MSDN article listing the steps to download the process template http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181511.aspx

To Answer your other questions,

Q. I am not sure why "Use this SharePoint Site" is listed as (Not configured)? Does the Team Foundation Server needs to have a local SharePoint instal for this option to be enabled? Or is it some kind of permission issue?

You have an option to set up the sharepoint site when you create a new team project, however you have an option of not creating a new team site with each team project and can skip this step and come back later to the team project to associate an existing team site to the team project.

Q. Also, when I enter the SharePoint site collection root URL in the "Use a Web site" textbox, there is not much change in the situation. How is one supposed to use this option?

You do not need the team site for this, unless you are planning to publish the excel using excel services to the sharepoint site.

Q. Does this mean that in order to use the workbook one needs to install SharePoint in TFS?

No.

HTH

Cheers,
Tarun

Comment: Thank you Tarun. I tried downloading the template, but I am not a Project Collection Administrator in TFS, hence, all the buttons in the Process Template Manager window is greyed out for me. I guess that is the reason why you need to download it to an access neutral location during the setup. I will ask my TFS admin to take the SharePoint portal route. This could be a permission issue afterall. Thank you again for your comment.

Comment: Yes you would need TFS Project Collection admin rights to download the process template (the reason for this is, once u have the rights, you can edit or even delete the process template). But the security rights for this are not related to the sharepoint security rights. Once u have the xls downloaded you will be able to progress with no other security access changes. Cheers.

Comment: As a TFS admin, the option for using the SharePoint site for Project portal is still greyed out for me, just like in the illustration above. Any suggestions/ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: I see, sorry i thought you wanted to know where you could access the worksheet from. However, to edit the information that you see grayed out at the moment. You need Edit-Project Level information. See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=VS.100).aspx scroll down to Project-Level Permissions